# Building call graphs using Clang AST, link parameters to arguments

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

I am trying to build call graphs using Clang AST.

Is there a way to somehow link the parameters of a function to the arguments of an inner function call?

For example, given the following function:

```
void chainedIncrement(int *ptr) {
    simplePointerIncr(ptr);

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        simplePointerIncr(ptr);
    }
}
```

I looking for a way to be able to link `ptr` from `chainedIncrement` function to the argument of `simplePointerIncr` function. Doing this will allow building a call graph.
Maybe there is a way of getting the same id while calling `getId()` on parameters and arguments.

I tried to use the following AST matcher:

```
functionDecl(hasDescendant(callExpr(callee(functionDecl().bind("calleeFunc")),unless(isExpansionInSystemHeader())).bind("callExpr");)).bind("outerFunc")
```

It seems that arguments are of type `Expr` while function parameters are of type `ParmVarDecl`.
Assuming that the parameter is passed as-is, without modification to an inner function, is there a way to link them somehow?

Thanks

**UPDATE**: Added my solution

There is a matcher called `forEachArgumentWithParam()`. It allows to bind arguments to a callee function to its parameters.

Another matcher, `equalsBoundNode()` allows to bind the parameters of the outer function, to the arguments of the callee function.

```
auto calleeArgVarDecl = declRefExpr(to(varDecl().bind("callerArg")));

auto innerCallExpr = callExpr(
        forEachArgumentWithParam(calleeArgVarDecl, parmVarDecl().bind("calleeParam")),
        callee(functionDecl().bind("calleeFunc")),unless(isExpansionInSystemHeader())).bind("callExpr");

auto fullMatcher = functionDecl(forEachDescendant(innerCallExpr),forEachDescendant(parmVarDecl(equalsBoundNode("callerArg")).bind("outerFuncParam"))).bind("outerFunc");
```

Comment: Can you specify the type of "call graph" you want ? AST is just a representation of the source code, it is possible to construct a Matcher to match the two `simplePointerIncr()` in the function. But it's more complicated if you want the information, for example the second call is in a for loop of 3 iterations etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a matcher called `forEachArgumentWithParam()`. It allows to bind arguments to a callee function to its parameters.

Another matcher, `equalsBoundNode()` allows to bind the parameters of the outer function, to the arguments of the callee function.

```
auto calleeArgVarDecl = declRefExpr(to(varDecl().bind("callerArg")));

auto innerCallExpr = callExpr(
        forEachArgumentWithParam(calleeArgVarDecl, parmVarDecl().bind("calleeParam")),
        callee(functionDecl().bind("calleeFunc")),unless(isExpansionInSystemHeader())).bind("callExpr");

auto fullMatcher = functionDecl(forEachDescendant(innerCallExpr),forEachDescendant(parmVarDecl(equalsBoundNode("callerArg")).bind("outerFuncParam"))).bind("outerFunc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example:

```
int add2(int var) {
  return var+2;
}
int caller(int var) {
  add2(var);
  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    add2(var);
  }
  return var;
}
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  int ret = 0;
  caller(ret);
  return 0;
}
```

use Clang-query to show the matcher result:

```
clang-query> match callExpr(hasAnyArgument(hasAncestor(functionDecl(hasName("caller")))))

Match #1:

~/main.cpp:5:3: note: "root" binds here
  add2(var); 
  ^~~~~~~~~ 

Match #2: 

~/main.cpp:7:5: note: "root" binds here 
  add2(var); 
  ^~~~~~~~~ 
2 matches.
```

It matches the function calls that use the parameter of function `caller`

Comment: Thanks, I have added my solution